# I am not able to update the MySQL database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update the mysql database using PHP but somehow I am not able to do the same. 
It echos the message that it is successfully updated but it doesn't update it. Please help.
Please check the code and tell me the correction: First I am showing the form then the PHP code

```
<?php
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql="select * from members_data where id='$id'";
$data=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($data);
?>

<form method="post" action="edit1.php" name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table  width="400" align="left">
<tr>
<td style="width:300px;">
Name
</td>
<td><input placeholder="What's the latest news?" type="text" name="name" style="height:20px;      width:300px;" value="<?php echo $row['name']?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:300px;">
Family Image
</td>

<td width="69%" height="25"><input type="file" name="file" style="height:20px; width:300px;" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:300px;">
Membership No.
</td>
<td><input placeholder="What's your membership number?" type="text" name="membership_no" style="height:20px; width:300px;" value="<?php echo $row['membership_no']?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:300px;">
Address
</td>
<td><input placeholder="What's the latest news?" type="text" name="address" style="height:20px; width:300px;" value="<?php echo $row['address']?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:300px;">
Contact Number
</td>
<td><input placeholder="What's the latest news?" type="text" name="contact_no" style="height:20px; width:300px;" value="<?php echo $row['contact_no']?>" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $res['id']?>" />
</td>
<td style="text-align:right; width:300px;"><input type="submit" name="edit1" value="Update" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Now starts the php code:

```
<?php
include("conn.php");
?>
<?php


if(isset($_POST['edit1']))
{
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "pdf", "doc", "docx");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/msword")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/plain")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    //echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    //echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    //echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    //echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    //echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("images/family_pics/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      //echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "images/family_pics/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      //echo "Stored in: " . "images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  //echo "Invalid file";
  }
$id=$_POST['id'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$image=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
$membership_no=$_POST['membership_no'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$contact_no=$_POST['contact_no'];

$query=mysql_query("update members_data set name='$name',family_image='$image',membership_no='$membership_no',address='$address',contact_no='$contact_no' WHERE id='$id'")  or die(mysql_error());

// if successfully updated. 
if($query){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='admin_detail.php'>View result</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}

}

?>
<?php /*?><script type="text/javascript">window.location="edit_records.php"</script><?php */?>
```

Comment: How does your query look when you just echo the SQL instead of executing it? Like so: `echo "update members_data set name='$name',family_image='$image',membership_no='$membership_no',address='$address',contact_no='$contact_no' WHERE id='$id'"`

Comment: what does your form look like?

Comment: form is alright. there is no problem in the form. can you please check the update query.

Comment: it is id field numeric or varchar ?

Comment: then you need to use WHERE id = $id...without quotes.

Comment: @NebojsaSusic removing the quotes would only increase the  sql injection vulnerability of the already very vulnerable code

Comment: i did, but still it doesnt help. can you copy paste the code at your end and see why it is not working

Answer (score 1):

The likely problem is with line:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $res['id']?>" />
```

I didn't see `$res` defined anywhere.

You probably want:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>" />
```

Also I recommend studying this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: lol!! I am such an idiot. Thanks buddy for showing that mistake. I was hitting my head on this since last 5 hours.

Comment: You're welcome, do read up on sql injection though :) I think the system will allow you to accept the answer after 10 mins.